# nodejs socket hang up timeout

Tags: node.js, request, timeout

It's essentially a timeout error for a long running process (about 30 minutes).

how can I increase the timeout for the request? I've tried `request.setTimeout(0, console.log);` but it's not having any effect on it.

```
var request = http.request({
    hostname: 'localhost',
    method: 'POST',
    port: 3000,
    headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    }
}, function(response){
    var body;
    var buffers = [];
    response.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));
    response.on('end', function(){
        try {
            body = Buffer.concat(buffers).toString();
        } catch(error) {console.error(body)}
    });
}).on('error', function(error){ // errors caught in here
    console.error("http error");
    console.error(error);
});

request.setTimeout(0, console.log);
```

**Error:**

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1103:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

**Edit**

[image]

**Screenshot 2**

The culprit is Formidable on the server end and is throwing aborted error

[image]

Comment: are you sure that is the only scenario this is happening, if the sever is busy doing something else you can  catch that error and retry the same request, or queue request for later

Comment: yes I'm sure. It's a unit test that I posted here, and the actual source code is really a long running process, tons of file uploads to cloud, about 30 minutes.

Comment: While I can see that actual source code is working but unit test (code above) simply gives up in 2 minutes (default timeout)

Comment: If I am reading your code correctly you are making a request to local server and the response is handling file transfer? in that case who ever is sending the files is responsible ending the connection... 

"ECONNRESET" means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly closed its end of the connection.

Comment: I think I found the culprit. It's formidable on the server end (see screenshot 2 in my question please) but I don't know how to tackle it. I see `aborted` in my console log. I'm not using expressjs, it's plain vanila nodejs app.

Comment: does this help: https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#aborted

Comment: not really, I mean i know it's getting aborted but what's causing it to abort and how can I prevent it?

Comment: sorry this where I would need to do more research on Formidable... Hope I helped a bit. But please when you find a solution make sure you post it here

Comment: this solved the problem. the httpserver timeout value. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout

Answer (score 0):

You need to set timeout before or when making a request.

```
var request = http.request({
    hostname: 'localhost',
    method: 'POST',
    port: 3000,
    timeout: 0,
    headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    }
}, function(response){
    var body;
    var buffers = [];
    response.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));
    response.on('end', function(){
        try {
            body = Buffer.concat(buffers).toString();
        } catch(error) {console.error(body)}
    });
}).on('error', function(error){ // errors caught in here
    console.error("http error");
    console.error(error);
});
```

API documentation is your friend ;) https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: no results, I've added a screenshot for my unit test. Please note that the actual source code under test is working without any problems and actually finishes uploading all files. The http request within unit test gives up early.